# Does opencv (image) template matching tolerate different kinds of distortion such as scaling, rotation, noise, fish eye distortion, and shearing?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Does OpenCV Template Matching work if a frame image from a live USB camera is at a different rotation, angle, light level, and noise level than a reference image?

I have a robotic industrial process with a digital USB camera mounted on a gantry.  Gantry moves camera to different locations to check the status of each location.  Each location needs to be visually checked for existence of specific objects.
There is a reference image file (such as RGB) for each object.
OpenCV Template Matching can find a reference image within a target image, such as finding a reference of previous 'snapshot' of specific object at a location within live camera frame image of same location.

However, camera angle to location may be at a different angle than the reference camera was to the image in the reference image.  And location camera may be at a different rotation, lighting level, and noise level than reference camera.

Comment: No, it slides a window the size of the template over the source image, and finds the best match according to the selected metric (doing pixel by pixel comparisons). Any sort of distortion, let alone scaling/rotation/shear will mess with that.

Comment: I would like to extend the comment of @DanMašek, OpenCV template matching doesn't support any kind of transformation, there are other modules in opencv-contrib which support scale invariant feature matching. Please follow this [link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html)